# How to create rtsp for multiple video by same port python?

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, rtsp, pygobject

Is it possible to create rtsp for multiple videos by same port like rtsp://12.0.0.1:8554/test will hold one video and rtsp://12.0.0.1:8554/test2 will hold another video, and both ports will be same?
I've tried the code below by threading, but it create the rtsp for first thread second thread and rtsp doesn't get generated.  How do I create rtsp for multiple video by same port?

This is the code:

```
import cv2
import gi
import threading
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstRtspServer', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GstRtspServer, GObject


class SensorFactory(GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory):
  def __init__(self, video,**properties):
    super(SensorFactory, self).__init__(**properties)
    self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
    self.number_frames = 0
    self.fps = 30
    self.duration = 1 / self.fps * Gst.SECOND  # duration of a frame in nanoseconds
    self.launch_string = 'appsrc name=source block=true format=GST_FORMAT_TIME ' \
                         'caps=video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=600,height=600,framerate={}/1 ' \
                         '! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ' \
                         '! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency ' \
                         '! rtph264pay config-interval=1 name=pay0 pt=96'.format(self.fps)

def on_need_data(self, src, lenght):
    if self.cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (600, 600)) 
        if ret:
            data = frame.tostring()
            buf = Gst.Buffer.new_allocate(None, len(data), None)
            buf.fill(0, data)
            buf.duration = self.duration
            timestamp = self.number_frames * self.duration
            buf.pts = buf.dts = int(timestamp)
            buf.offset = timestamp
            self.number_frames += 1
            retval = src.emit('push-buffer', buf)
            print('pushed buffer, frame {}, duration {} ns, durations {} s'.format(self.number_frames,
                                                                                   self.duration,
                                                                                   self.duration / Gst.SECOND))
            if retval != Gst.FlowReturn.OK:
                print(retval)

def do_create_element(self, url):
    return Gst.parse_launch(self.launch_string)

def do_configure(self, rtsp_media):
    self.number_frames = 0
    appsrc = rtsp_media.get_element().get_child_by_name('source')
    appsrc.connect('need-data', self.on_need_data)


class GstServer(GstRtspServer.RTSPServer):
  def __init__(self,video,stream,**properties):
    super(GstServer, self).__init__(**properties)
    self.set_service("8012")
    self.factory = SensorFactory(video )
    self.factory.set_shared(True)
    self.get_mount_points().add_factory("/"+stream, self.factory)
    self.attach(None)
    

video ='/home/root1/Documents/test_videos/videoplayback.mp4'
stream = 'test'
stream1 = 'test1'

GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)

server = threading.Thread(target=GstServer, args=(video,stream,)).start()
server1 = threading.Thread(target=GstServer, args=(video,stream1,)).start()
loop = GObject.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```